# How to use if statement in batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, environment-variables, conditional-statements

I have the following for loop in my batch file:

```
for /f %%y in ('findstr /C:"%%c" out.txt ^| sed "s/.*%%c \([^>]*\).*/\1/i"') do SET RESULT=%%y
echo.%%a;%%b;%%c;!RESULT!>>D:\outputTA.txt
```

My variable in for loop is `%%y` and I want to use if statement in a way:

```
if my variable > 1000 then

set Result to round my variable / 32

else 

set Result to round my variable
```

Does anyone know how I can do this in Batch file?

Comment: Hint: `help if`, `help set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in ("!RESULT!") do (
if %%A LSS 1000 (
    set int=%%A
    if not "%%B"=="" (
        set decimal=%%B
        set decimal=!decimal:~0,1!
        if !decimal! GEQ 5 (
            set /a int+=1
        )
    )
) else (
    if %%A GTR 1000 (
        set /a int=%%A/32
    set /a int+=1
    )
    )
   echo !int!
  echo.%%a;%%b;%%c;!int!>>D:\outputTA.txt
```